# Dynamic cluster changes for Spark Streams

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and wondering about its ability to change dynamically over time, my main interest is in the Streaming ability of Spark.

From what I understand the Stream part ends as soon as the input (DStream) is created, from that part its the core Spark engine which handles the data.

My main concern is about the dunamics of the cluster, in the code Spark the cluster can be updated each time a batch coimputation is started/scheduled. But the Streams should be invoked by the intervals which are set.

My Question is how flexible is the cluster? if I am using a cluster manager as Zookeeper I saw (can't find the reference now) that a worker nodes **can** be dynamically associated with the Zookeeper. But are SparkContext that flexiblly attached? can I have more than 1 SparkContext in the cluster and can they be dynamically added/deleted?

EDIT: What I am trying to achieve is a dynamic cluster, suppose I am running a machine learning algorithms on the data, at first I have to run only one algorithm where the duration of the delay is 1 second, so I start a StreamContext with duration=1sec, later I want to add another algorithm but I need a timeout of 5 seconds, my question is whether I can add the second StreamContext to the cluster dynamically (not stopping the entire execution of the cluster).

Comment: Could you make your question clearer? I have tried to read it several times, but I don't understand what your concern is. :S What do you want to achieve? And what do you mean by dynamically added/deleted?

Comment: @Markon Hi and thank you for trying to assit I added an edit with a more detailed example please take a look at it and I would be glad to answer anymore questions

Comment: Can't you just create two different jobs?

Comment: You might have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29614314/126125

Comment: @Markon Hi and thank you for your answer it was very helpfull. Isn't it wastefull to hold different job for each stream? of course it's a possible solution but I was hoping I could only define a StreamContext for each job and assign all the cores for all the algorithms.

Comment: No, actually it's a better solution - at least, feasible ( it seems there are no ways to create multiple contexts https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243 ). It's better also under a deployment perspective - not just a coding point of view.